# How is a "l.js" file loading on my php page

Tags: javascript, php, performance, security, safari

I was checking for some load latency on a php page I am building.
I discovered some resources that I wasn't loading:

- l.js

  - r.js
  - icp
  - s.gif

I disabled all css and js files (including jquery) in my page but still see these files loading. The s.gif is especially disturbing because the request has the URL of my php file on it and I really don't want that information out there. (I am running the server over https for security but don't want to have to put a user login on top of the server.

I am serving on OS X Server and using Safari as the debugger and load analyzer.

Comment: We cant trace code for you without seeing whats happening ourselves. If them files are not part of your app then you have bigger problems. Why would a missing image show a url, you mean a php error/warning right?

Answer (score 0):

This issue did not show code that explaind where the resource requests were coming from. I started disabling browser extensions and that did the job. Apparently they were injecting resource requests with the downloaded pages.